# Gradle Build Failed Error: package javax.servlet does not exist

Tags: build, gradle

I am pretty new to gradle and build systems,
I am trying to build project with gradle, but it cannot find packages of Tomcat server that I use in several classes of my project.

My build config:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
   flatDir { dirs "WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" }
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.orientechnologies', name: 'orient-commons', version: '1.3.0'
    compile group: 'com.orientechnologies', name: 'orientdb-client', version: '1.3.0'
    compile group: 'com.orientechnologies', name: 'orientdb-core', version: '1.3.0'
    compile group: 'com.orientechnologies', name: 'orientdb-graphdb', version: '1.3.0'
    compile group: 'com.orientechnologies', name: 'orientdb-enterprise', version: '1.3.0'
    compile group: 'com.tinkerpop.blueprints', name: 'blueprints-core', version: '2.3.0'
    compile group: 'com.tinkerpop.blueprints', name: 'blueprints-orient-graph', version: '2.3.0'
    compile group: 'com.tinkerpop', name: 'pipes', version: '2.3.0'
    compile group: 'com.tinkerpop.gremlin', name: 'gremlin-java', version: '2.3.0'
    compile group: 'com.tinkerpop.gremlin', name: 'gremlin-groovy', version: '2.3.0'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.9.5'

}
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'test'
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.3'
}
war {
    from 'WebContent'
}
```

Errors occur, when I launch Gradle Task - Build:

```
OrientDBFilter.java:6: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
OrientDBFilter.java:5: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.Filter;
```

....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Usually you would use `providedCompile`. Something like:

```
providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'
```

Then your app will compile, but gradle won't include the servlet api in the final war file.

Comment: why won't it compile with the `compileOnly` group?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution with `providedCompile` did not work, but simply
`compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'` did work.

I just wanted to share this if somebody has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and this line worked

```
compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.1'
```